# Cast typed class to a more general type

Tags: c#

I have a method that returns `DbSet`s with different entities, but these entities all implement the same interface. Something like this:

```cs
public interface ICommentHost
{
    IList<String> Comments { get; }
}
public class A: ICommentHost { /* snip */ }
public class B: ICommentHost { /* snap */ }
public class C: ICommentHost { /* snup */ }



public static  DbSet<ICommentHost> GetDbSet(int variable, MyDbContext dbContext)
{
    switch (variable)
    {
        case 1: return dbContext.As; // DbSet<A>
        case 2: return dbContext.Bs; // DbSet<B>
        case 3: return dbContext.Cs; // DbSet<C>
        default: throw new System.ArgumentException("Invalid variable: " + variable);
    }
}
```

Which I want to use something like this:

```cs
[HttpGet("{hostType:int}/{id:int}/comments")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyCollection<String>>> GetAllComments(int hostType, int id)
{
    return GetDbSet(hostType, _dbContext).SelectMany(e => e.Comments).Distinct().ToImmutableList()
}
```

Of course, since this is always the same for each type of entity, I want to use the same code, too.

(And, just to spell it out: it's example code, condensed from a multi-project solution. The current solution does not use `int`s, it uses whatever you think is the best type to use for this use-case. And it's not just this one method, I'd like to implement the entire REST endpoint like this, there are more complex queries, so copying code like an animal is not the solution I'm striving for here.)

My problem is how to even specify the return value so its usable for me. I have a Java background, and there I would either return `DbSet` without any type (which does not work in C#) or cast all results to a base class.

For casting I tried:

```cs
return (DbSet<ICommentHost>) (object) GetDbSetA();
```

Which throws

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[A]' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[ICommentHost]'.

And:

```cs
return (DbSet<ICommentHost>) Convert.ChangeType(GetDbSetA(), typeof(DbSet<ICommentHost>));
```

Which throws

> System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

How would I go about implementing this method the C# way?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: _"How would I go about implementing this method the C# way?"_ - I would not abstract to an int variable (Which is probably an enum?). You could instead take a type argument, bounded with "must implement ICommentHost".

Comment: Why an int parameter coming in?  Just because of unsure how to implement?  Ok.  Now for the return.  Do the class instances of A, B and C already exist somewhere else?  Please edit your post and try to provide more about the specific sub-classes and how they are implemented to return the DbSet<X> context.  Your List<string> in the interface does not make sense if all of them are all intended to return that.  Again, please EDIT your post, dont just comment as a reply.

Comment: Generics in C# do not support variance, except the limited case of interfaces explicitly marked as variant. A `DbSet<A>` cannot be cast to `DbSet<ABaseType>`, because `DbSet` is a concrete class. If this were allowed, it would open up the door for scenarios where a `DbSet<A>` was "forced" to store a `B` if `B` also derived from `ABaseType`. Per the comments of others, the correct way to implement this is "not at all". Your `GetDbSet` method should be written differently -- as to how, exactly, depends on the context. For example, a `GetDbSet<T> where T : ICommentHost` with a type switch on `T`.

Comment: Just because `A` inherits from `ICommentHost` it does not mean that `DbSet<A>` inherits from `DbSet<ICommentHost>`. It doesn't. You can't make that assignment.

Comment: What is your `hostType` variable in your real code, if it is not an `int`? And is `DbSet<T>` the `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>` type?

Comment: @Enigmativity Is there a type that would make the task easier? I'd probably try an enum first, but -again- I'm a Java developer where enums are a lot more powerful, so maybe string would suffice, too. And no, it's a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<TEntity>`.

Comment: `IEnumerable<ICommentHost>`?

Comment: @SteffiS. - You cannot do what you're hoping to do with that `DbSet`. It's impossible to make that `DbSet<A>` cast to `DbSet<ICommentHost>`. It'd be like being able to cast `Bowl<Apple>` to `Bowl<IFruit>` - you'd be able to add a `Banana` to a bowl of apples if you could!

Comment: @SteffiS. - I'd be stunned if Java let you do it!

Comment: @SteffiS. - What you can do is project a `DbSet<A>` to a `IEnumerable<ICommentHost>`. That'd be easy.

Comment: @Enigmativity In Java you can cast `List<A>` to `List<? extends ICommentHost>` which acknowledges that you don't know the concrete type of the list, and you can only do read operations on the list. Or -since the typing does not exist after compiling- you could cast it to `List<ICommentHost>` and even add Bs without problem, because in Java each `List` is a list of objects.

Comment: @SteffiS. - That's awful.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well... you have to know what you're doing. Which is true for every programming language. The problem is that I don't know how to do the same in C#. How do you "project"  `DbSet<A>` to a `IEnumerable<ICommentHost>`?

Comment: @SteffiS. - By doing `dbSetA.SelectMany(e => e.Comments)` - or something like that. `Select` and `SelecMany` are both projections.